# Virtualenv not working with executable .py file

Tags: python, macos, shell

I was having a problem getting a python script to run in the shell:

```
$ chmod u+x scratch.py
$ ./scratch.py
./scratch.py: line 3: import: not found
sys.version_info
$
```

What am I doing wrong here?

scratch.py:

```
# /usr/bin/env python

import sys

print sys.version_info
```

Comment: That's not a shebang. `# /usr/bin/env python` should be `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Yeah, silly mistake. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the shebang's `!` at the top of your script, so the shell is not recognizing your script as a Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
 ^
```

Comment: Dang! Good spot, annoying I missed it.